# Set Private Route to Parent Layout to prevent 'uid' getting undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on a Reactjs project. To maintain Auth flow using firebase auth I have set up a auth context that handles the Auth Functions(login, logout, etc..) and I can use the **currentUser** to refer to the user in other components.
When I log out, the uid becomes **null**, when this happens I redirect the user to **SignIn Page** using my custom **Private Route**.
Here is my Private Route:

**PrivateRoute.js (Excluded Import/Export)**

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
const { currentUser } = useAuth();
return (
    <div>
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props=> {
                return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/SignIn' />
            }}
        >
        </Route>
    </div>
)
}
```

Also, this is my **App.js (Excluded Import/Export)**

```
function App() {
return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Notes} />
            <PrivateRoute path='/MakeNote' component={MakeNote} />
            <Route path='/SignUp' component={SignUp} />
            <Route path='/SignIn' component={SignIn} />
            <PrivateRoute path='/MyProfile' component={MyProfile} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

Now, as you can see the NULL uid can be easily handled in my **Notes, MakeNote and MyProfile** components as user will be redirected to **Login Page**,
**BUT,** as i cannot figure out a way to handle NULL uid in the **Layout component**, as soon as I log out it throws **null error**

**Exact Error** = `TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null`

**Error in Layout Component Line** = `const userUid = currentUser.uid;`

I know this might be a basic logic that I am missing out here, but I'll be glad if I can get some help in getting this fixed so that that **null uid** can be handled in the `<Layout> component`.

Thank You.

Comment: try using  `currentUser?.uid`
it will not throw a error any more.
but you have to handle what will happen if the `currentUser?.uid` does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with older JS:

```
const userUid = currentUser || currentUser.uid
```

or with newer:

```
const userUid = currentUser?.uid
```